# What can happen to my LED strip with a missing resistor?

Tags: voltage, led, resistors, led-strip

I have a 144pixel rgb light strip with 5050 leds on it and one of the resistors broke off on one side. I use a battery pack to power it and at times a wall adapter. What's strange to me is that is still works fine no issues whatsoever but I'm concerned about long term effects it might have if any. Should I be concerned? My strip is in a silicone sleeve making it difficult to get a clear picture of it but this image is has a red arrow pointing at the spot that broke off on the same exact strip.

[image: rgb]

Comment: Show a picture of the strip with the damage visible.

Comment: normally a missing resistor would cause some of the LEDs to not light., hare a picture so we can see exactly what type of strip you have.

Comment: The marked part is a capacitor, not a resistor.

Answer (score 1):

These LEDs looks like addresables RGB LED WS2812B or similar. On the picture you indicate capacitor. In the [datasheet](https://www.sinistercircuits.com/docs/WS2812B_18031509254757.pdf) on p.4 you find more information about purpose of this component in this circuit.

This is 100nF filter capacitor and must be place as close as posible to LED betweene VDD and GND. If you remove this component your circuit (LED strip) could work not properly.

Answer (score 0):

The picture shows a bypass capacitor, which stabilizes voltage when LEDs flip in/off. Without it the pixel will be more sensitive to voltage drop and noise, but since this is such a dense strip there are enough capacitors nearby that it won't matter. The adjacent capacitors are close enough to compensate.

The strip will almost certainly work like normal. I would not be concerned.